# Xcode MacOS completely unaware of minimum deployment target

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

Does Xcode not understand the minimum deployment target in build setting?

[image: Minimum Deployment Target]

My Project after a build and run:
[image]

Any help to resolve these errors would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Your first screenshot shows the deployment target for the project. What's the deployment target for the app target? Select the target from the target list on the left side of the project editor and click the General button at the top of the project editor to see the target's deployment target. You may have to set the target's deployment target to macOS 12.

Comment: @SwiftDevJournal it's the same as the project. Xcode 13 is a disaster. Thanks for your help anyways.